# に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった

Tags: grammar

[コントロールに苦しまなくなった野球系YouTuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNWQDu8XXpM)

You would want good control as a pitcher so, "to become not-suffering in control" or "attain good control" is the default way of reading this.

but what exactly is コントロール**に**? i have to resort to reading it as コントロールは/が...

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This に marks the cause/reason of one's feelings or pychological reactions. For example:

- Aに驚く　to be surprised *at* A
- Aに悲しむ　to feel sad *about* A
- Aに怒る　to become angry *with* A
- Aに戸惑う　to be puzzled *by* A
- Aに感動する to be moved/impressed *by* A

So コントロールに苦しむ means "to suffer *from* (one's bad) control". コントロールが/は苦しむ means something like "(Mr.) Control suffers", which makes no sense here.