# Meaning of に in この狭さに

Tags: meaning

I'm struggling to understand how the bolded part in the below sentence changes the meaning of the sentence.

I think that 狭さ refers to narrowness(in context that they are both walking close together in a very tight space), but I am not sure which に this is and how it is modifying the rest of the sentence.

> 七菜海のリアクションが、可愛くてそれでなくても、**この狭さに**、密着でドキドキの俺は、悟れまいと尤もらしいことを言う

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010

Comment: so if I understand correctly is marking the cause/reason for ドキドキ?