# Understanding のに

Tags: grammar

> 透徹**と**紅い瞳が昼間の戦域の空に向く**のに**、同じ方を見やった。あの、昼間の超長距離砲。
>
> 「……次は直接基地狙ってくるかと思ったが、意外とこねえな」
>
> 「重砲の役割は面制圧か固定目標の破壊だ。機甲兵器を狙い撃つようにはできてないし、一個戦隊如きに使うものでもない。あれも都市か要塞が本来の目標だろう。試射ついでにこちらに向けてみた、くらいじゃないか」
>
> ライデンは低く嗤った。
>
> 「ついで、で四人か。つくづくやってられねえな」
>
> 「完成すれば四人どころか共和国が滅ぶ。おれたちにはどうでもいいが、……少佐はそうもいかないだろうな。対策がとれればいいけど」
>
> 淡々と言う**のに**、ライデンは内心ふぅんと思う。本人は気づいていないようだが。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Are both the bold のに of the same usage? I think they mean "seeing that" or "because” rather than "despite". Or do you have other interpretations?

By the way, is the bold と after 透徹と of the same usage as 意外と (namely, that と changes 透徹 into an adverb)?

Edit:
The preceding text is quoted as follows:

> シンはちらりとライデンを見やって、無言で肩をすくめた。本当に気にしていないようだが、それでいいとライデンは思う。覚悟を決めて、全霊を尽くした果ての死だ。その責を負えるのは結局は、死んだ当の本人だけだ。

Comment: What's 紅い瞳? Someone's scarlet eyes or some weapon? Can you share the previous sentence?

Comment: @naruto Thank you for your answer. The first sentence says seeing シン looking at the sky, ライデン looked in the same direction. シン had red eyes so 紅い瞳 refers to シン's red eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not のに meaning "although; despite", but probably の as a nominalizer followed by に meaning "upon; against; at; in reaction to". Basically this should be the same に as in ～に驚く, ～に苦しむ, etc. See: [に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010)

- 彼がそう言ったのに驚いた。
  I was surprised that he said so.
- 蓋が開かないのに困っています。
  I'm having trouble opening the lid.
- 淡々と言うのに、ライデンは内心ふぅんと思う。
  Upon hearing his emotionless statement, Leiden thought ふぅん (Meh?) within himself.
  <sub>(I'm not sure what this ふぅん implies; see the following context)</sub>

I said "probably" because this type of (の)に is normally used with certain verbs related to psychological reactions. 思う is not a verb commonly used with ～(の)に, but it makes sense to me. However, the first sentence sounds unnatural because 同じ方を見やる is not even a psychological reaction... Maybe it's a typo, or maybe this is some sort of his habit in writing?

I have never seen 透徹と. [BCCWJ](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/) has 44 examples of 透徹 but no example of 透徹と, so I think this is a mere misuse. Still, it's clear that the author tried to use it as an adverb by adding と.

Comment: I just edited my question by adding the text previous to 透徹と紅い瞳が昼間の戦域の空に向くのに、同じ方を見やった. So what do you think is the natural way to say it, if のに is deemed as unnatural?

Comment: @chinoalpha Okay so I can confirm the first のに is not "despite", so the only remaining interpretation, albeit unnatural, should be "upon". The natural way of saying this is 向くのに合わせ, 向くのを見て, 向いたのに気づいて, etc.