# Can 〜ているつもり mean "intend to do"?

Tags: grammar

> 「ぴっ」
>
> 「……ファイド。起動してるとエナジーパックを無駄に喰うから、明日起こすまで待機状態に切り替えておけと命じたろ」
>
> 「ぴ」
>
> 「………………わかった。好きにしろ」
>
> 頷くように光学センサが瞬いたものの、ファイドの巨体は動く気配を見せない。不寝番を交代してシンが眠るまで、共に**起きているつもり**なのだろう。忠実な、そして頑固な従者のように控え続ける姿と、辟易**と**ため息をついているシンの様子にフレデリカはくすりと笑みを零し……それからふと、眉を顰めた。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉 安里アサト

Does this bold ているつもり mean "intend to do…" in this context? Or can ているつもり mean "intend to do…"? I always think it can only mean "one thinks she/he is doing…, but the reality is different". If it does mean "intend to do" in this context, why isn’t 起きるつもり used?

By the way, is the bold と quotative と? Like 辟易と(思って)ため息をついている?
Or is it some other usage?

PS: ファイド is a robot belonging to シン.

Answer (score 3):

～ているつもり can express one's future plan, too. This ている refers to the continuation of state/action:

- 2時に起きるつもりだ。
  I intend to get up at 2:00.
- 2時まで起きているつもりだ。
  I intend to stay awake until 2:00.
- 明日は家でテレビを見るつもりです。
  I'm going to watch TV at home tomorrow.
- 明日は家でテレビを見ているつもりです。
  I'm going to stay home watching TV tomorrow.

---

This 辟易と is not a correct usage of 辟易. 辟易 is a suru-verb, so it should have been 辟易しながら or 辟易しつつ in this context. 辟易とする is a [mistake some native speakers make](https://biz-journal.jp/2019/02/post_26458.html) (I found 6 instances of this mistake in BCCWJ), but using 辟易と without する as a standalone adverb is out of the question to me (no similar instance in BCCWJ). This reminded me of [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/94421/5010) about the same work... (辟易と思う makes no sense, either, because 辟易 is not the content of thinking.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on the context.

Intention of doing
受かるまで受験し続けるつもりだ
いつまで無職でいるつもり？

Self recognition that is not true
理解してたつもりなんだがなぁ…（実際は理解してなかった）