# Understanding ~ことに

Tags: grammar, light-novel

I am trying to read GJ部 and I've come across this:

> 紫音さんの細い指が喉元で動く。 三人の手が三人とも違っている**ことに**、軽い驚きがあった。

I think this sentence means something like "Shion-san's thin fingers moves around his neck. He was slightly surprised at how different each of the three girls' hands feel", but I don't really understand what ことに is doing in this case.

Context: This guy couldn't tie his tie so 3 girls offered to help him, the first two also tied it wrong and while the third girl was trying to tie it the narrator said this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This こと is a nominalizer, "(the fact) that ...". This に is a particle used with 驚き. ～に驚く is a common set phrase meaning "to be surprised *at* ～". See also: [に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72042/5010)

A literal translation is "There was a mild surprise at the fact that three hands were all different".